# Missing processing menu in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2, orfeo-toolbox

I'm sure there is a really simple explanation to this but haven't found any pointers on this forum or elsewhere. I seem to have lost the 'Processing' menu from QGIS and can't figure out how/why!?

Any ideas what I might have done to make this happen?

I'm running QGIS 2.8 built against GDAL 1.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: I am having this problem as well. The processing toolbox is installed in the plug-in manager but I cannot find it anywhere. HELP And i cannot edit or uninstall/reinstall processing toolbox plug-in--it's locked.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Processing menu is tied to the Processing plugin. So please check if you have deactivated the Processing plugin in the Plugin Manager.

[image]

Comment: To enable it, go to Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins... -> Installed and check the checkbox next to "Processing".
PS. I didn't deactivate it for sure, it must just happen.

Comment: mine shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'` error when I'm trying to reload Processing or during startup. Processing toolbar isn't visible because of it. any idea?

Comment: This should really be on by default.

Answer (score 3):

Processing sometimes crashes or takes a long time to load. so sometimes QGIS disables it. As @underdark answered, re-enable it from plugins menu.

Comment: Working with QGIS 3.4.9, Processing was checked in the Plugins but not appearing on the menu bar. Unchecking and then checking the box again helped it reappear.

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora (and possibly other GNU Linux distributions) QGIS is split into multiple packages. Run:

```sh
dnf search qgis
```

and then install any packages that seem relevant. On other distributions replace `dnf` with the name of your package manager e.g. `apt`. Installing `python3-qgis` and `qgis-grass` did the trick for me.