# Can't find the option to clip or union with only selected features in QGIS (2.18.11)

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, clip, union

I just downloaded the new version of QGIS (2.18.11) and I can't find the option to clip or union with only selected features

[image: I've attached an image of what I see]

Typically, there was a selection where you could choose only the selected layers.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146591/missing-processing-menu-in-qgis