# After updating to QGIS 3.20.2 vector processing tools are missing

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing, tools, gui

In my QGIS 3.20.2 I can't use tools from the Vector menu as I used in the previous QGIS version. See the print screens. Can somebody tell me why as well as how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning the processing tools off and on under plugins?

Comment: Relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146591/missing-processing-menu-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-of-qgis

Answer (score 2):

Try to tick the **Processing** (it is a core QGIS plugin) from the `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins`

[image: processing]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem - it was Settings - User profile.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)