# Missing Geoprocessing Tools and Field Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector

I am currently facing an issue with my QGIS software (version 3.32 LIma). The geoprocessing tools for both vector and raster operations have suddenly stopped working, and I can't seem to locate these functionalities anywhere. Additionally, the Field Calculator is also unresponsive. Even after reinstalling QGIS to the Long Term Release (LTR) version 3.28.15 "Firenze," the problem persists. It appears as if there may be an issue with Python.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and if so, could you please provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Comment: For the missing geoprocessing, it seems that resetting the user profile can be the solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408672/after-updating-to-qgis-3-20-2-vector-processing-tools-are-missing?rq=1

Comment: I had problems with QGIS freezing for no reason about a year ago. Simply reinstalling did not help I had to: 1) Uninstall, 2) Searching and deleting all files and folders with either qgis or osgeo in the path or file name, 3) install QGIS. I use the OsGeo4w install

Answer (score 3):

Since you write that you can't locate them (i.e. the 'processing' section is gone from the status bar), I assume you have an issue that I have enocuntered, too. I don't know what's the cause but for me the follwoing steps resolved it:

Go to: `Plugins > Installed`.

Then:

- uncheck the box from the'Processing' Plugin.

[image]

- Check the box from the'Processing' Plugin again (it should reapear now):

[image]